# ngx-pinch-zoom angular 7 toggle zoom using event not working it's gives error in console

Tags: angular7

My angular version is 7.

Here, somePinchZoom found undefined all code and implementation working image show and also zoom icon works but i want to implemt custom icon for zoom.
and

```
import { PinchZoomComponent } from 'ngx-pinch-zoom';

somePinchZoom: PinchZoomComponent;
@ViewChildren(PinchZoomComponent) pinchZoomComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.somePinchZoom = this.pinchZoomComponent.find(elem => elem.id === 'somePinchZoom');
    console.log(this.somePinchZoom); // undefined
}

zoomInDoc() {
   this.somePinchZoom.toggleZoom();
}
```

Html

```
   <pinch-zoom id="somePinchZoom">
      <img src="my_img_url" alt="">
   </pinch-zoom>
   <button click="zoomInDoc()"> zoom </button>
```

When i click on my custom zoom button it's gives error in console.
ERROR TypeError: "this.somePinchZoom is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<pinch-zoom #myPinchZoom="pinchZoom"
```

TS

```
@ViewChild('myPinchZoom') pinchZoomComponent;
```